# comparison among input numbers

Tags: list, dictionary

i want have comparison among input numbers .general shape of input numbers is like this :

n

x1 x2

x3 x4

x5 x6

x7 x8

n indicates how many input line we have and on each line we have 2 number with space ,just 2 number,
the first part of line is price and the second is quality
for example like this :

4

1 5

7 9

5 6

20 30

in line two '1' is price and '5' is quality
if i can find more quality with lower price i print 'yes' if not print 'no'

i write this but i can not change list to dictionary

```
 x = int(input())
count =0
y= []
while count!=x:
    y.append(input())
    count+=1
z= []
for i in y:
    z.append(i.split())


def dictionary(x):

    d={x[0]:x[1]}

    return d


for h in z:

    a=dictionary(h)
```

for example i want

```
2

1 10

7 3

'yes'
```

or another example :

```
4 

1 5

7 9

5 6

20 30

'no'
```

i hope someone answer this

Comment: if we find more quality with lower price we print 'yes' if we do not print 'no'

Comment: i really need this .please someone answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
n = int(input())
q,p = map(int, input().split())
for _ in range(n-1):
    q1,p1 = map(int, input().split())
    if q1 > q and p1 < p:
        print("yes")
        break
else:
    print("no")
```

This works. The code is really simple.